# リストに名前と点数を追加し、最後にまとめて表示したい

Tags: python

今pythonでリストに名前と点数を追加できるコードを書いています。
以下のコードは名前と点数をリストに追加、そしていつコードを終了するのを試すテストコードで、問題なく動くきます。ただ、書きたいコードは名前と点数を最後にまとめてプリントするコードが書きたいのですが、どのような変更をすればいいですか？様々なアドバイスを聞けるのを楽しみにしています。

現コード

```
def listofname():
    members = []
    scores = []
    done = False
    while done != True:
        Students = input("Enter a name or enter 'done' when finished")
        if Students == "done":
            done = True
        
        else:
            members.append({"name": Students})
            Score = input("Enter score")
            scores.append({"Score": Score})
        
        print(members)
        print(scores)

print(listofname())
```

プリントされるデータ

```
[{'name': 'Tanaka'}, {'name': 'Yamada'}, {'name': 'Kojima'}]
[{'Score': '70'}, {'Score': '20'}, {'Score': '80'}]
```

プリントしてほしいデータ

```
[{'name':Tanaka, Yamada,Kojima}]
[{'Score':70,20,80}]
```

もし可能であればリストに追加された名前の数のプリントと点数の最高点、最低点、平均点もプリントできるコードの書き方も教えていただけると幸いです。

長文失礼しました

Comment: リストに辞書を追加しているのは何か理由があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問文にある「期待する出力結果」はシンタックス・エラーになります。

```py
[{'name':Tanaka, Yamada,Kojima}]
[{'Score':70,20,80}]
```

以下、`name`, `Score` を辞書のキーとして、値をリストにするコードです。
※ `int(Score)` の部分で `ValueError` が発生する可能性があります。

```py
def listofname():
    members, scores = {'name': []}, {'Score': []}
    while 1:
        Students = input("Enter a name or enter 'done' when finished ")
        if Students == 'done': break
        members['name'] += [Students]
        Score = input('Enter score ')
        scores['Score'] += [int(Score)]
        
    print(members)
    print(scores)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listofname()

# {'name': ['Tanaka', 'Yamada', 'Kojima']}
# {'Score': [70, 20, 80]}
```

Comment: +1: 質問者さんのコードの時点でこうなっているのですが、`print(listofname())` の部分は `listofname()` で良さそうです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu ご指摘、どうもありがとうございます。

Comment: 「期待する出力結果」はシンタックス・エラーじゃないですよ。出力結果なので。直すなら質問を直してもらいましょう。